# filling with NaNs based on minimum numeric value

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I have a matrix A and I would like to fill NaNs in each column upto the point where a numeric value is encountered.

Example

```
A = 
     [ 0 0 0
       0 0 6
       5 7 0]
```

should be

```
A = 
     [NaN NaN NaN
      NaN NaN 6
      5   7   0]
```

Is there a way to vectorize this problem rather than doing it in a two for loops step

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it posible that a column contains all zeros? What should be done then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`max`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/max.html) to find the first nonzero (if any) in each column, and then [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to generate a mask for the values that should be set to `NaN`:

```
[valid, row] = max(A~=0);
row(~valid) = size(A,1)+1; %// in case some column contains all zeros
A(bsxfun(@lt, (1:size(A,1)).', row)) = NaN;
```

Comment: Smart solution! And best thing is that it uses `bsxfun`!

Comment: @Divakar It's always great to use `bsxfun`

Answer (score 0):

@Luis as a great answer, but since Matlab 2016b:

> you can directly use operators instead of bsxfun. <sub>Source: [bsxfun](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)</sub>

The last line of Luis' suggestion can be replaced by: `A((1:size(A,1))' < row) = NaN;`

Hence the whole code is:

```
[valid, row] = max(A~=0);
row(~valid) = size(A,1)+1; % in case some column contains all zeros
A((1:size(A,1))' < row) = NaN;
```

It also seems that this solution runs faster.